# how to generate a password for htpasswd file using php

Tags: php, web-applications

Hi how can i generate a password using php, to use for the htpasswrd file.
which encoding we are using?

Answer (score 1):

It's better to delegate to the `htpasswd` app with `system()` and the like rather than to roll your own.

Also consider using a database and mod_auth_mysql or similar for auth.

Answer (score 1):

here the link

http://www.htaccesstools.com/articles/create-password-for-htpasswd-file-using-php/

```
<?php
// Password to be encrypted for a .htpasswd file
$clearTextPassword = 'some password';

// Encrypt password
$password = crypt($clearTextPassword, base64_encode($clearTextPassword));

// Print encrypted password
echo $password;
?>
```

Please note: For Apache servers running on Windows you have to use the htpasswd program to generate passwords, or use the htpasswd generator.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
$new_password = password_hash($old_password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
```

> password_hash() creates a new password hash using a strong one-way
>   hashing algorithm. password_hash() is compatible with crypt().
>   Therefore, password hashes created by crypt() can be used with
>   password_hash().
>
> (...)
>
> PASSWORD_BCRYPT - Use the CRYPT_BLOWFISH algorithm to create the hash.
>   This will produce a standard crypt() compatible hash using the "$2y$"
>   identifier. The result will always be a 60 character string, or FALSE
>   on failure. Supported Options:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php